# Backbone - Assign index to models on instantiation

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Is there anyway to let the newly instantiated model know of its 0-based index inside its collection, and assign it? Something like:

```
var m = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.set('index', '// 0-based index inside the parent collection//');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the index of a model on a collection by using indexOf

```
collection.indexOf(model)
```

or if you don't have access to the collection in your view but you know the model is inside a particular collection, you can always get the collection like this:

```
model.collection.indexOf(model)
```

I wouldn't recommend storing the index on a model, because then each time you add an additional model you will have to update the index values for each model on a collection.